# How can I pass input to Java application inside the Kubernetes container?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I have configured Kubernetes service (of type `LoadBalancer`) hosted on AWS EKS. The service's pods run in interactive mode (which is needed to run the container in the pod). The container in there is running a simple Java .jar application that receives input and produces output based on that.

**The question**: how can I pass input to Java application inside the Kubernetes container?

Here is the part of *yaml* configuration of the pod that ensures it runs in an interactive mode:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ardulat/mckinsey
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: anuar-mckinsey
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    stdin: true
    tty: true
```

The pod is up and running. As you see from the configuration, it receives TCP connections.

Here is the service of the pod:

```
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)          AGE
anuar-mckinsey   LoadBalancer   10.100.239.207   a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com   8080:32516/TCP
```

I can ensure that the pod and service are configured correctly by looking at the logs of the pod that output a print message from Java application in the container.

**Already tried**:

- curl application in a verbose mode that produces:

```
*   Trying 18.190.142.22...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com (18.190.142.22) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.63.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

- connecting via netcat in a verbose mode that produces the output:

```
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif en0
    src 172.20.22.204 port 51144
    dst 18.190.142.22 port 8080
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com port 8080 [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!
```

**Final thoughts**: so it seems like the configurations are right and the service runs on the cluster hosted on AWS EKS. The logs produce the right output. However, I can't send the message (through TCP connection?) to the Java application inside the container. Any thoughts on how I can pass the input to it?

Comment: Is the port exposed?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, the port is exposed inside the service and pod. The port is the same everywhere, 8080. And you can see from curl and nc outputs that the connection is there.

Comment: This might just be the load balancer you hit, not your pod.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ok, sounds reasonable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Double check your ingress configuration

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the ingress configuration is ok. I ensured it from the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Comment: `telnet a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com 8080` (there is a space between the host and port number). then enter the text command you want to send and press Enter.

Comment: @apisim does not work either. It connects and exists right after it

Comment: Hmm...`kubectl port-forward` to the pod, then connect with telnet to localhost at the local port that was forwarded? Another option could be to get a shell in the container with `kubectl exec` and then connect to the app locally.

Comment: @apisim already tried using `port-forward` and the output is the same as I was doing for the service with external IP. `kubectl exec` does not solve the problem for accessing the service externally

Comment: Perhaps it will help if you'd describe how the Java application expects to receive the input. Does it use `System.in`? Or does it open a plain TCP server socket on port 8080 and expects commands over that socket? Or is there an HTTP server listening on port 8080? BTW - i can connect with `curl -v telnet://a8154210d09da11ea9c3806983848f2f-1085657314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8080` just fine and submit 2 commands (type in text, press Enter) before the connection is closed.

Comment: @apisim thank you for taking the effort to curl my application. However, I checked the logs of all pods and nothing has changed. Regarding the way how the Java application receives input, yes, it uses `System.in`. You can see the full code here: https://github.com/ardulat/mckinsey/blob/master/src/Main.java (line 13 is the way I receive the input).

Comment: Looked at the code - the app isn't listening on port 8080. I'm sorry but there's no way to communicate with the app in the container from outside over port 8080. My successful attempt to connect was probably connecting to the ELB.

Comment: @apisim Yes, right, the app itself does not listen on the port. I run it inside Docker container which is being called from a pod that listens on the port 8080.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the setup. Before suggesting to change the app from using `System.in` to opening and listening on a `ServerSocket`...one last suggestion: `kubectl -n <namespace> attach <pod-name> -c <container-name> -i -t`. Notice that the container name is required.

Comment: @apisim it seems like I can connect to my app through `kubectl attach`. I paste the input and it gives output as it was expected. Thank you for your help! How can I access it from the outside world? Using service? Because if I want to deploy my application and I want somebody to run the same command without accessing pods directly I would have to use services.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in comments, the information was that the Java application uses `System.in` to receive the input. That is usually equivalent to `stdin`.

A way to send input to the application in the container and get output is by [attaching](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#attach) to the process in the container in raw terminal mode, which connects the local `stdin` and `stdout` with the container's:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> attach <pod-name> -c <container-name> -i -t
```

On the additional question about how to access the application from the outside without accessing pods directly and by using a Service, I'll suggest:

- Change the application so that it creates a `ServerSocket` to listen and accept connections at a particular port number.
- Read from the socket's input stream individual lines and have them processed as if the input were from `System.in`.
- Write the result to socket's output stream.
- Expose the port via a LoadBalancer Kubernetes Service like you already had.

[This here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) could be a good starting point for the new code. You can use `telnet 127.0.0.1 <port>` or `curl telnet://127.0.0.1:<port>/` to test the application locally and when not running it in a container.

Exposing an HTTP-based service instead, in my opinion, seems like an overkill for this application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to define the arguments.

```
env:
- name: MESSAGE
  value: "hello world"
command: ["/bin/echo"]
args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]
```

And you just defined an argument for your kubernetes pod here.

Besides it would be good to configure your pods to use a **configMap** or **Secrets**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker for building your kubernetes image, then you can use ENTRYPOINT or CMD attributes in your docker file for passing arguments while launching your application. Please refer below link for more information.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/